# Could a Web.UI.Page object (C#) correspond to a .html file, rather than a .aspx file?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, system.web

I was checking the System.Web.UI.Page class methods and instantiation examples listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx

In this case, the front-end file is an .aspx file and is linked to the back-end .cs file via this meta header: 
    <%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="pageexample.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyCodeBehindCS" %>

Could a Page object also be tied to a pure .html file? If yes, then how are they tied to each other?

Comment: Please explain exactly what your end goal is. It might be you're just looking for URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot produce a page ends with "html" as a result, because the IIS have to know what kind of page it's dealing with, in order to follow the .Net life-cycle.

However, you can consider the Page is already produces a pure HTML file, since it's the only code that the browsers can understand. If you want to have the same on developer's view, just don't use the benefits of .aspx objects.

But of course, you can find workarounds too. You can create an HTML file with Javascript codes which triggers the .aspx pages needed, and puts the results. By the look of the user, it's all will be looking like an HTML file. (And Javascript ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

One option, though keep in mind you're technically fooling IIS in this instance:

1. Open IIS Manager and select the target website.
2. Open HandlerMappings applet
3. Copy the mapping where Path is `*.aspx` into a duplicate where path is `*.html`.

Then, add a handler in your config to tell IIS what to do with this file type:

```
<httpHandlers>
   <add path="*.html" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
</httpHandlers>
```

**Note:** If you have HTML pages *without* server-side code in them, this could end up being troublesome. You may be better off just exempting extensions altogether and look at using routing.